# Keyboard layout changed (13.10/ Asus Q301L)

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit installed on my Asus VivoBook Q301L. I plugged in a USB keyboard, and now my layout seems to have changed, and I can't change it back.

I noticed that my USB keyboard has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-keys starting from the left edge to the space bar.

My laptop has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>. The issue is that some of my keys are typing wrong characters:

<kbd>0</kbd> key types <kbd>/</kbd>

<kbd>P</kbd> key types <kbd>*</kbd>

<kbd>;</kbd> key types <kbd>-</kbd>

<kbd>/</kbd> key types <kbd>+</kbd>

If I want the actual characters, I have to hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key on my laptop (e.g. "laptop would be "la*to*" if I didn't hold the Fn key). I have run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and selected Asus laptop for my keyboard.

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is very likely that you need to turn off Num Lock on the external keyboard.

I had this very problem. When I plugged the external keyboard in, the num lock was on, and cused those keys to believe they were part of a number pad (which this particular model doesn't have). Even after I unplugged the keyboard, the setting of the numlock stayed, causing those keys to continue to output the wrong characters. It wasn't until I plugged the keyboard back in and turned off the numlock that keys reverted to their normal state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, and it still didn't work. I have since returned this laptop for a better one anyway, and haven't had this issue with the new one (Lenovo IdeaPad U430).

Answer (score 1):

After searching for quite some time, I have found a solution to this problem.

Open up notepad and copy/paste:

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("wScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
```

And save as `whateveryouwanttocallit.vbs`

If you double click this then it will turn the num lock on and off.

Cheers,

Ace

IF you get stuck here is the video that help me find the solution (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8J7TJBSBPo)

Comment: Although it should not matter, the example has a break between ("wScript.Shell") and WshShell